# Input text CSS name color not taking effect

Tags: css, forms

I have a contact form with several controls and i am unable to set the color of the name that appears in the control prior to a user typing in their details. I attempted to use `color` however this changes the color of the value the user inputs.

```
/* Contact Form */
input[type="text"]#name { 
    color: #000000;
    background-color : #ffffff; 
}
```

Comment: share your HTML also.

Comment: It would help people to comment on why this requires a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to style the placeholder. It's different across browsers currently.

Here is Bootstrap's mixin for it - you can see what the generated CSS will look like.

```
.placeholder(@color: @input-color-placeholder) {
  &::-moz-placeholder           { color: @color;   // Firefox
                                  opacity: 1; } // See https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/11526
  &:-ms-input-placeholder       { color: @color; } // Internet Explorer 10+
  &::-webkit-input-placeholder  { color: @color; } // Safari and Chrome
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
input[type="text"]#name{}
```

It is refering the input which has type text and has id="name". Please update it.